# Erro: [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Como resolvo o erro: [object HTMLInputElement]

O código deveria salvar o texto digitado no campo, e mesmo dando F5 ficar salvo, exemplo: igual o script desse site.

```
function digGet(){
    // Cria um item "usuario" com valor "Thiago Belem"
    var login = document.getElementById("user_login");
    window.localStorage.setItem('usuario', login);
    saveGet();
}

function saveGet(){
    // Depois, em outra página ou aba, recupera esse item
    var usuario = window.localStorage.getItem('usuario');
    document.getElementById('user_login').value = usuario;
}

function delGet(){

    // Remove o item
    window.localStorage.removeItem('usuario');
}

//Rodar no load do DOM
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){ 
    saveGet();
});
```

Comment: Por favor, seja mais claro no seu problema, pois nem a mensagem completa de erro você colocou. E faça isso **editando** a pergunta, não nos comentários. Comece descrevendo o que seu código deveria fazer e o que está acontecendo. Coloque, também, a mensagem de erro completa e elabore um [mcve].

Comment: A varável `login` é um elemento do dom no método digGet, acredito que você deva escrever o *value*.

Comment: Olá Jeferson, há por aqui muita gente que percebe de JS :) Olhando para o teu código `.setItem('usuario', login)` vejo que estás a tentar guardar um elemento do DOM no `localStorage` que guarda só strings. Isso não vai dar. Acho que o que queres é usar `.value` ou `innerHTML`... tipo: `var login = document.getElementById("user_login").value;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neste trecho, está faltando o *value*

```js
function digGet(){
    //Correcao aqui
    //Antes login era um elemento do Dom e nao o valor do elemento
    var login = document.getElementById("user_login").value;
    
    
    
    window.localStorage.setItem('usuario', login);
    saveGet();
}
```

Comment: obrigado amigo, conseguir resolver o problema de gravação e.e

Comment: @JefersonSantos blz mano